# Redis pub/sub for single receivers

Tags: python, redis, rabbitmq

I am a `RabbitMQ` user exploring `Redis` and have two questions regarding the pub/sub mechanism

1. Can I publish messages to the system where each client (consumer) removes the entry for other clients? I want to publish 100 tasks but each tasks should be processed only by 1-single subscriber.
2. AFAIK, by default all messages are always broadcasted/published to all clients. What if one client takes 1 second to process the message, and another takes a minute. What would be the limits here? Would be some messages dropped at some point?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

1) That's not how pub/sub works. Publish doesn't care or know about being received, it just publishes a message. Every subscriber that is subscribed will receive it and you can't stop this

2) That's up to you to handle client logic.

From the sounds of it, redis pub/sub might not be the system/pattern you're looking for. You should look into `zeromq` especially, `push` and `pull` sockets, which instead of publishing messages, push messages to specific sockets one time. If you read through the [starter documentation](https://zeromq.org/get-started/) many patterns are explained and something will work for your specific case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Redis lists to pop data in consumers.

https://redis.io/docs/data-types/lists/